# Truncate/delete first x rows from a Frame

Tags: c#, deedle

I have a `Frame<int, string>` which consists of a OHLCV data. I'm calculating technical analysis indicators for that Frame and since the first few records aren't accurate due to the fact that there are at the very begin, I have to remove them. How do I do that?

```cs
public override Frame<int, string> PopulateIndicators(Frame<int, string> dataFrame)
{
    var candles = dataFrame.Rows.Select(kvp => new Candle
    {
        Timestamp = kvp.Value.GetAs<DateTime>("Timestamp"),
        Open = kvp.Value.GetAs<decimal>("Open"),
        High = kvp.Value.GetAs<decimal>("High"),
        Low = kvp.Value.GetAs<decimal>("Low"),
        Close = kvp.Value.GetAs<decimal>("Close"),
        Volume = kvp.Value.GetAs<decimal>("Volume")
    }).Observations.Select(e => e.Value).ToList<IOhlcv>();
    
    // TODO: Truncate/remove the first 50 rows
    
    dataFrame.AddColumn("Rsi", candles.Rsi(14));
}
```

Comment: Would `dataFrame.Rows.Skip(50).Select(...)` work for you?

Comment: @KlausGütter, thanks for your comment! `RowSeries<int, string>` doesn't have a definition for `Skip`. However, thanks for the idea, I could do Skip on the array before adding it to the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operations in Deedle are expressed in terms of row keys, rather than indices. The idea behind this is that, if you work with ordederd data, you should have some ordered row keys.

This means that this is easier to do based on row keys. However, if you have an ordered row index, you can get a key at a certain location and then use it for filtering in `Where`. I would try something like:

```
var firstKey = dataFrame.GetRowKeyAt(50);
var after50 = dataFrame.Where(kvp => kvp.Key > firstKey);
```